# GMSAutocompleteViewController not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am trying to find a my address "Royal castle apartments A-block" In android device its listing in search but iOS device la not listing that above address and I tried setting country code as well nothing works.

I have added VC life cycle method

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        containerView.alpha = alpha
        containerView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.withAlphaComponent(backgroundOpacity)
        shadowView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.withAlphaComponent(backgroundOpacity)
        self.mapView?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.compassButton =  true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
          //Location Manager code to fetch current location
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        startAnimating(type: animationType)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        autocompleteController.delegate = self
         // Specify the place data types to return.
        let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) | UInt(20) |
            UInt(GMSPlaceField.placeID.rawValue) | UInt(GMSPlaceField.formattedAddress.rawValue) | UInt(GMSPlaceField.coordinate.rawValue))!
        autocompleteController.placeFields = fields
        UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        var codeToFilter = "IN"
        let countryLocale = NSLocale.current
        let countryCode = countryLocale.regionCode
        if let country = (countryLocale as NSLocale).displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.countryCode, value: countryCode!){
            print(countryCode!, country)
            if let cc = countryCode{
                codeToFilter = cc
            }

        }

        // Specify a filter.
        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = .address
//        filter.country = codeToFilter
        autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter

        // Display the autocomplete view controller.
        present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have added delegates method given by place sdk

```
extension MapDragVC: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

    // Handle the user's selection.
    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
//        print("Place name: \(place.name)")
//        print("Place ID: \(place.placeID)")
//        print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
//        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(13.067439, 80.237617)
        self.mapView.clear()
        self.addMarker(location:
            place.coordinate)
        self.geocodeCoordinates(location: place.coordinate)
        print("Place name: \(place.formattedAddress)")
//        if let formmattedAddress = place.formattedAddress{
//            self.addressLbl.text = formmattedAddress
//        }
//        if let coordinates = place.coordinate{
//
//        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

            })
         }

     }

    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
        // TODO: handle the error.
        print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
    }

    // User canceled the operation.
    func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
//        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

            })
        }
    }

    // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
    func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }

}
```

As document i have added code https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete

Comment: Am also facing the same issue. Place picker, place SearchResult nothing is working.

Comment: show your delegate methos implementation.

Comment: @kjoe question updated

Comment: the firts code is in viewDidLoad?

Comment: check now @kjoe

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change filter to no filter

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.type = .noFilter
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score -1):

I'll see it try this.

```
     let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        containerView.alpha = alpha
        containerView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.withAlphaComponent(backgroundOpacity)
        shadowView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.withAlphaComponent(backgroundOpacity)
        self.mapView?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.compassButton =  true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
          //Location Manager code to fetch current location
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        startAnimating(type: animationType)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        autocompleteController.delegate = self
         // Specify the place data types to return.
        let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) | UInt(20) |
            UInt(GMSPlaceField.placeID.rawValue) | UInt(GMSPlaceField.formattedAddress.rawValue) | UInt(GMSPlaceField.coordinate.rawValue))!
        autocompleteController.placeFields = fields
        UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        var codeToFilter = "IN"
        let countryLocale = NSLocale.current
        let countryCode = countryLocale.regionCode
        if let country = (countryLocale as NSLocale).displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.countryCode, value: countryCode!){
            print(countryCode!, country)
            if let cc = countryCode{
                codeToFilter = cc
            }

        }

        // Specify a filter.
        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = .address
//        filter.country = codeToFilter
        autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter

        // Display the autocomplete view controller.
        present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

you must set the delegate inside the viewDidLoad Method, since there is not guaratee that the delegate is set with your aproach.